# Silent Installer - to install scripting langues from winform Application

Tags: c#, python, ruby, winforms, silent-installer

I am developing Winform application, using C# on .NET 4.0, which need to install scripting langue(s) based on the user selection. What is the best way to detect if a particular scripting environment/Engine for a given langue(Ruby, python, Perl, etc) is installed on client machine and silently install it if not already installed.

Comment: Does it need to be totally silent? I'd be pretty pissed if an application started installing scripting environments without me knowing.

Comment: hmmm ... I see your point ... my target is just to give 'everything' the user need without bothering him/her to much .... i doesn't hurt if the app ask for conformation though

Comment: For Python, check if there's a folder `C:\Python*` and that there's something in it. That's the way Python manifests itself in Windows. You could also try searching the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I agree with idea that a truly "silent" install might not be desirable for the users, there are many different installer packages that support silent installation.

[This page](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) actually has a good breakdown of the various installers and the command arguments needed to do unattended and silent installations.  I am more familiar with MSI and it has [lots of options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024%28VS.85%29.aspx).

So if you go this route, you'd fire up a Process (uh, Task I guess in C# 4) and run an installer.